# NSMutableArray EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have no idea why, but my NSMutableArray 'items' will not take more than 5 elements.

Can someone please help? I'm following the Big Nerd Ranch iOS Programming book.

This code works fine:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    BNRItem *p = [BNRItem randomItem];
    [items addObject:p];
}
```

However if I change the initial value of i to 4 or less the program crashes when exiting the for loop:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 4; i < 10; i++) {
    BNRItem *p = [BNRItem randomItem];
    [items addObject:p];
}
```

Error screenshot: http://db.tt/3CdueSYh

Comment: This code looks ok and the error most likely is somewhere else. Try to debug with breakpoint at the exception throw and see where your code is actually crashing

Comment: I used breakpoints to narrow down the crash to where the for loop is exited. This seems like a crazy error!

Comment: can +randomItem method be a problem?

Comment: I think it might be! It's throwing up this error now - http://db.tt/Y3T65cN9   Issue appears related to [NSArray arrayWithObjects].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your

```
NSArray *randomNounList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bear", @"Spork", "Mac", nil];
```

to:

```
NSArray *randomNounList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bear", @"Spork", @"Mac", nil];
```

You forgot `@` before `"Mac"`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

In the screenshot you posted in your comments you are adding a C string, `"Mac"`, to your `randomNounList` array.  You need to make this an NSString with an @ symbol.

I suspect the crash is occurring when this entry is randomly selected.

I'm surprised this compiled, I suspect you are ignoring some warnings.

Comment: Ouch, well spotted! I was starting to think it was something to do with the array being autoreleased too early... Thanks!